# jsTree sort function ridiculously slow

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am writing a Chrome extension for Delicious bookmarks. My background.js file fetches the bookmarks on browser open and creates the object required for jsTree to build a proper tree.

If I disable jsTree's sort plugin, the bookmarks appear immediately when I click the popup. If I enable the sort function there is a ~2 second delay between click and displaying of data.

I tried pre-sorting all of my data in the background script and passing it to the popup pre-sorted, but jsTree does not honor this sorted data.

I only have ~90 tags and ~400 bookmarks. Is there a config option I can use to make this faster? Here is what my jsTree looks like.

```
$('#jstree').jstree({
    'close_all': -1,
    'core': {
        'animation': 0
    },
        'json_data': {
        'async': true,
        'data': data
    },

    'progressive_render': true,
    'themes': {
        'theme': 'classic',
        'dots': false,
        'icons': true
    },

    'sort': function (a, b) {
        return this.get_text(a) > this.get_text(b) ? 1 : -1; 
    },

    'types': {
        'valid_children': [ 'folder' ],
        'types': {
            'folder': {
                'valid_children': [ 'file' ],
                'max_depth': 1
            },
        }
    },

    'plugins': [
        'json_data',
        'themes',
        'sort',
        'types',
    ]
});
```

Comment: Just a comment:  I don't know why yours is slow, but I am running jstree with a server side call that traverses a directory recursively - at least 300 files, and returns the html - and then I loop through all of the html with `$.each` and it returns in less than a second.  My point is that the problem may lie elsewhere.

Comment: Instead of adding other options, try disabling each option you can, just to see if it gets faster... e.g. try to disable the sort function, since you have it pre-sorted...

Comment: what is ``this.get_text`` doing?  maybe that's the expensive function?

Answer (score 2):

jsTree uses the native array `sort` method, so the only thing that can be improved is the calls to `get_text`, but I doubt that can get much quicker.

If you have your data presorted - simply remove the sort plugin from your `plugins` config array. There is no way for the sort plugin to "know" that the data is already sorted, just remove the plugin.